# Is there a way to disable GitHub-hosted runners in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Due to security reasons, we need to explicitly disable GitHub-hosted runners, ideally for the entire organization. Any clues on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> we need to explicitly disable GitHub-hosted runners

The answer to that seems to be: no.
You cannot disable a [GitHub-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners).

You can only [control access to larger runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/controlling-access-to-larger-runners) that have been added to an organization or enterprise.

But that applies only to GitHub Team or GitHub Enterprise Cloud plans, and the larger runners feature is currently in beta for organizations and enterprises.

---

For *self-hosted* runner, you can either:

---

### Delete (as a form a "deactivation") / recreate a GitHub runner:

Since there does not seem to be one global setting, you might need to script a process which would:

- loop over your repos/organizations
- use the [Self-hosted runners API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners)
- [remove any self-hosted runner found](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/removing-self-hosted-runners) (same for [GHE - GitHub Enterprise)](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/removing-self-hosted-runners#removing-a-runner-from-an-enterprise=).

---

### [Stop and disable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service) the service launching a self-hosted runner

But that does not apply to GitHub-hosted runner.

Comment: I do not want to remove the self-hosted runners.

Comment: @Sl4dy I understand: I did not see a way to disable it directly, hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same worry.  I came up with an idea (not in practice) that is a bit of a pain...

for anything in .github/workflows/*.yaml, check the yaml to make sure self-hosted is in there; if not, refuse the merge/commit.

Comment: `self-hosted` is the default label, self-hosted runners can be given other labels or targeted via their runner group. It would be better to check that there are no hosted labels like `ubuntu-latest`, `windows-latest`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a script svc.sh deployed along with other scripts at the time of installation of runner.

You can manually stop the runner using the following

```bash
$ sudo ./svc.sh

Usage:
./svc.sh [install, start, stop, status, uninstall]
Commands:
   install [user]: Install runner service as Root or specified user.
   start: Manually start the runner service.
   stop: Manually stop the runner service.
   status: Display status of runner service.
   uninstall: Uninstall runner service.

## Stopping the runner would be
$ sudo ./svc.sh stop
```

If you control your runner configurations using ansible then this can be automated for selective set of runners as per requirement.